# Notifications for volatile attributes in EMF

Tags: java, volatile, transient, emf, ecore

In an Ecore model with an attribute that is declared as transient and volatile (its value is calculated from several other fields), is there a canonical way to generate notifications for changes to this field (i.e. when one of the fields that the transient volatile field depends on changes, check if the value of the transient field is affected by this change and send a notification)?

The way I would do this at the moment is to register a listener on the owner of the transient attribute that reacts to changes to the dependencies and triggers notifications if the calculated value changes, but this is a lot tedious manual work that I'd like to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

You will be aware that EMF comes with its own Adapters. Adding adapters isn't actually such tedious work, and I'd suggest that in your case this may well be the best option (in fact, generating the model code will include these adapters, cf. [this blog post about what every developer should know about EMF](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2011/03/22/what-every-eclipse-developer-should-know-about-emf-part-1/)).

If you want to add such notification functionality by hand, you could simply attach an `EContentAdapter` to the root element of your model, which will listen to changes in the whole element tree. This way you could avoid adding an adapter to every single model class.

There's a [simple tutorial on `Adapter` and `EContentAdapter`](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseEMFNotification/article.html) by Lars Vogel.

Comment: The first link has nothing to do with transient/volatile fields and the answer is very vague.